# Передача аргументов функции в обработчике события

Tags: javascript

Какие есть способы, а самое главное как правильно передавать аргументы в функцию в обработчике событий
Например:

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.nav');
var ul = menu.querySelector('ul');
function handler(event, bool) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if(event.target.tagName == 'LI') {
        if(bool) {
            ul.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        } else {
            ul.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }

    }
}
menu.addEventListener('mouseout',handler.bind(null, event, false), false);
menu.addEventListener('mouseover',handler.bind(this, event, true), false);
```

Вроде работает, но разнице нет какой контекст я передаю в `bind`, хоть `this`, хоть `null`, хоть `вася`....
Далее. Изначально код функции был такой:

```
function handler(event, bool) {
    if(event.target.tagName == 'LI') {
        var ul = menu.querySelector('ul');
        if(bool) {
            ul.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        } else {
            ul.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }

    }
}
```

При этом `event` == `undefined`,  `ul` == `undefined`.
Добавил в начало функции строку: `event = event || window.event;` - `event` появился, вынес `var ul = menu.querySelector('ul');` из функции стало работать.
Так как же правильно передавать аргументы?

Comment: Какой бы способ Вы не нашли, это все равно будет говнокод! Хандлеры это процедура, которая обязана принимать только одно свойство с типом event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `handler.bind(null, false)`

С сигнатурой `function handler(bool, event)`

`handler.bind(null, false)` как раз вернёт функцию с одним аргументом для события.

```js
function handler(bool, event) {
  console.log(bool, event);
}

let handleFalse = handler.bind(null, false);
let handleTrue = handler.bind(null, true);

handleFalse('Event 1');
handleTrue('Event 2');
```

Либо можно использовать замыкание(если не нужен контекст `this`):

```js
function getHandler(bool) {
  return function handler(event) {
    console.log(bool, event);
  }  
}

let handleFalse = getHandler(false);
let handleTrue = getHandler(true);

handleFalse('Event 1');
handleTrue('Event 2');
```

---

Ну и соберём в кучу:

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.nav');
var ul = menu.querySelector('ul');
function handler(bool) {
  return function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if(event.target.tagName == 'LI') {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = bool ? 'red' : '';
    }
  }
}

menu.addEventListener('mouseout',handler(false), false);
menu.addEventListener('mouseover',handler(true), false);
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1
    <li>Item 2
    <li>Item 3
    <li>Item 4
  </ul>
</div>
```

Хотя, на мой взгляд, `.nav li:hover{}` куда лучше

Comment: не надо тут bind

Comment: _если не нужен контекст this_ - у тебя во всех решениях контекст теряется. И, кстати говоря, во втором случае он хотя бы будет равен элементу на который идет подписка

Comment: @Grundy, придираешься же. Очевидно, если автору нужен контекст, он вместо null в bind напишет menu

Comment: очевидно, если бы автор знал, что так можно - он бы не задавал тут вопрос. Кроме того, ответы читают другие пользователи кроме автора, вообще не знакомые с работой bind, и как работают события

Comment: т.е. других вариантов нет, кроме как использовать промежуточные переменные?

Comment: При чём тут промежуточные переменные, это просто демо, без DOM. Добавил с элементами.

Comment: Я понял принцип, в вариантах с `bind` вы возвращали результат `bind` в переменные, затем уже "новые" функции использовали в обработчике. Я про это спрашивал. Конечно лучше через css это исключительно пример для того, что бы  понять как это все работает

Comment: Всё, что можно присвоить в переменные, можно использовать в качестве выражений как есть. Это всё тот же javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы контекст имел значение - в функции обработчике нужно явно использовать `this`.

Первым параметром в `bind` нужно передать тот объект, который бы вы хотели видеть в качестве `this`.

Воспользуюсь спиппетом от @vp_arth.

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.nav');

function handler(bool, event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if(event.target.tagName == 'LI') {
    // в оригинале красится весь список, поступим так же
    this.querySelector('ul')
        .style.backgroundColor = 
              bool ? 'red' : '';
  }
}

menu.addEventListener('mouseout',handler.bind(menu, false), false);
menu.addEventListener('mouseover',handler.bind(menu, true), false);
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1
    <li>Item 2
    <li>Item 3
    <li>Item 4
  </ul>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что в функции-обработчике `handler.bind(menu, false)` `this === menu`, и `bool === false`.

---

Рассмотрим, в чём ошибки вашего кода.

`handler.bind(null, event, false)` - Вы создаёте функцию здесь и сейчас, привязывая:

- `null` в качестве `this`,
- глобальную переменную `event` в качестве первого параметра(на данном этапе она равна `undefined`)
- `false` в качестве второго параметра

В итоге, при возникновении события, происходит вызов `handler(undefined, false, event)` в контексте `null`(т.е. без контекста), результаты которого вы и видели.

Comment: Действительно, недочитал я вопрос. =)

Comment: Вон оно что, т.е. когда я передавал в `bind` что угодно кроме `menu`, и при этом  выборка `ul` находилась в функции, он честно мне говорил что внутри этого объекта нет элемента с таким селектором. Но постойте, у меня было `var ul = menu.querySelector('ul')`, т.е. он влюбом случае должен был обратиться к глобальной `menu`, не так ли?

Comment: _в контексте null(т.е. без контекста)_ - на самом деле будет использован глобальный объект, в данном случае _window_

Comment: @Grundy, это без `use strict`

Comment: И еще, `event`  в объявлении функции сделали последним аргументом, пусть аргументов будет десяток, он все равно последний, как необязательный, о чем говорит строчка: `event = event || window.event;`  и в `bind` его не передаем, так как это объект быдет получен только при возникновении события. И если в дальнейшем будет необходимо обработчик удалить, необходимо использовать промежуточные переменные. Так как событие с обработчиком привязанным через `bind` удалить нельзя.

Comment: @pepel_xD, строка `event = event || window.event;` не нужна, она напоминает о тех старых временах, когда некоторые браузеры не передавали event первым параметром.

Comment: Действительно, `var ul = menu.querySelector('ul')` сработало бы, если бы не ошибка строчкой выше: `undefined.target.tagName`

Comment: @Anon, ага, дошло... выполнение то остановилось на ошибке....

Answer (score -2):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var theVal = "спасибо за минус дружище )-";

btn.addEventListener("click", function(event, str = theVal){ alert(str); });
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

### одна функция на два события с разными параметрами

```js
function work(str){
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = str;
}

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event, str = 'спасибо за минусы'){ work(str); });
btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event, str = 'и одному человеку за плюс ✌'){ work(str); });
```

```html
<div id="btn">click</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53928/discussion-on-answer-by-perfect------).